Extending Injectivity of a Fourier Multiplier Operator from $C^\infty_c$ to $L^2$ Using Density Arguments
Suppose an operator $T$ is well-defined on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but its injectivity is explicitly established for functions in the subspace $C^\infty_c$. Given the dense embedding of $C^\infty_c$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, is it the case that injectivity of $T$ on $C^\infty_c$ implies its injectivity on the entirety of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
Here's a brief overview of the operator's characteristics:

The operator $T$ acts as a Fourier multiplier, with a multiplier that covers the entire real line, thereby preserving all spectral information (i.e., it does not annihilate any part of the spectrum).
The inverse Fourier transform (IFT) used in defining $T$'s action is considered valid only for functions in $C^\infty_c$.

Given this setup, I am curious about the following:

Main Question: Can we use a density argument, or approximate general $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions by sequences of $C^\infty_c$ functions, to conclusively demonstrate that $T$ is injective on all of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Specific Concerns:

How does the limitation on the IFT's validity (being constrained to $C^\infty_c$) impact the argument for extending injectivity from $C^\infty_c$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?
Are there specific properties or conditions (such as continuity or boundedness of $T$) that are crucial for this argument to hold?



I am seeking insights, detailed explanations, or references that could clarify whether the density of $C^\infty_c$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, along with the spectral preservation property of the Fourier multiplier, suffices for extending injectivity to the larger space.
Thanks
EDIT:
Lets assume $T$ is bounded: $$|Tf|_H \leq C|f|_{L^2}$$

In general, injectivity on a dense subspace does not imply injectivity on the entire space, even assuming boundedness, unless you have something like there exists $C > 0$ such that $|Tx| \geq C|x|$ for all $x$. So unless you’re in that case, I wouldn’t count on a density argument. However, a Fourier multiplier is simply, by definition, after conjugating by a unitary, a multiplication operator, and whether it’s injective or not depends only on the measure of the set on which the function takes value $0$…

… By “with a multiplier that covers the entire real line”, I’m assuming you meant the multiplier function never takes value $0$, so in particular the operator is injective. The argument you need is not using density of $C^\infty_c$ to directly conclude that injectivity passes to $L^2$, which is in general not true (and there are even examples of Fourier multipliers which is not injective on $L^2$ but injective on $C^\infty_c$), but using density of $C^\infty_c$ to extend Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform to unitary operators…

… thereby concluding that injectivity boils down to injectivity of the multiplication operator on $L^2$ of the frequency domain. And it is then easy to prove that multiplication by a function which is a.e. nonzero must be injective.

This also means you don’t need boundedness of $T$ for this to work, as long as you define everything correctly. For example, the (closure of the) derivative operator is injective on $L^2$ (or rather, on $W^{1,2}$, the dense subspace on which it is defined), which can be proved by the same argument.

Thanks for the comments @DavidGao! so the key property is that the multiplier is non-zero a.e.. and this extends beyond $C^\infty_c$ by the argument you laid out. if its not too much trouble, do you have a reference which could help fill some more holes i have with respect to this and other matters related to fourier multipliers.

The multiplication operator with the indicator function of the interval, say $[-1,1]$, should be injective on $C_c(\mathbb{R}.$

@APIs Sorry, I don’t know of any good reference on the topic. Presumably most standard reference books on harmonic analysis would contain some results of this nature?

Let $ f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with ${\rm supp}\,f\subset [-a,a].$ Then the function $$F(z)=\int\limits_{-a}^a  f(t)e^{-2\pi  izt}\,dt$$ is holomorphic in the entire complex plane and coincides with the Fourier transform of $f$ on $y={\rm Im}\,z=0.$ By analycity if $F(z)$  vanishes on the interval $-1\le x\le 1,$ $y=0,$ then $F=0,$ hence $f=0.$
Consider the multiplier operator $M$ with the function $m(x)=(1-|x|)_+.$  Then $m(x)F(x)=0$ implies  $F(x)=0$ for $-1\le x\le 1.$ Thus $f=0.$ This shows that $M$ is injective on $C_c.$ Clearly $M$ is not injective on $L^2,$ as it vanishes on all $L^2$ functions whose Fourier transforms vanish on $[-1,1].$
By the inverse Fourier transform we can explicitly give the formula for the operator $M.$ Namely $M$ acts as the  convolution with the positive integrable continuous function ${\sin^2(\pi t)\over \pi ^2t^2}.$
Remark 1 The kernel of operator $M$ contains functions in $L^1.$ It suffices to consider a smooth function $F$ with support contained in $[1,2].$  Its inverse Fourier transform is absolutely integrable. @David Gao observed, in the comment below, that the operator corresponding to the indicator function of the complement of a  closed nowhere dense set  with positive measure does not vanish on $L^1.$
Remark 2  Clearly there are proper subspaces $V$ of $L^2$ such that for any multiplier $M$ operator, if $M$ is injective on $V,$ then $m$ is nonzero a.e., i.e. $M$ is injective on $L^2.$ For example $V$ may consist of all functions $f$ such that $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{f}(x)|^2(1+|x|)\,dx <\infty $$

The situation can be even worse. For example, the Fourier multiplier associated with the indicator function of the complement of a fat Cantor set would be injective on $L^1$ (as the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is continuous and the complement of a fat Cantor set is dense), but clearly not injective on $L^2$.

@DavidGao Nice example!  Although it  is impossible to give the explicit formula for the corresponding convolution operator.

That’s true. I don’t think there’s any way to explicitly calculate the inverse Laplace transform of the indicator function of a fat Cantor set.

Thank you @RyszardSzwarc and DavidGao. I really appreciate the insight and effort!
